# Copy Chart from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to copy multiple charts on one sheet, to another workbook as an image. It copies as a reference and not an image

```
wb.Sheets(w).ChartObjects("Chart 27").Chart.ChartArea.Copy
wb.Sheets(w).ChartObjects("Chart 19").Chart.ChartArea.Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plots").Paste
```

I would like for the charts to be images, and not a direct copy with references. Also, for the charts to appear below one another, when I paste, it does it right on top of eachother

I want it to start at a certain cell, for example "A2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the charts to be pasted as images you must use this method:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plots").Pictures.Paste
```

To have the charts placed below one another, you must first select the target cell where you want the chart to be placed.

Comment: Cool, I am trying to place the chart, but it places it randomly, and only replaces latest one

Comment: You have to call this method after each chart copy that you make, and previously select the target cell.